# What kind of mushroom is this?

Tags: species-identification, mushroom

I picked it this evening beneath an oak, in France, Nantes :

[image: Three in a row]
[image: Please give me a hand]

I tried an image search with Google, and it seems I picked a finger of a dead hand :)

[image]

What is its name, and is it edible?

Comment: Did you try the image search after cropping the fingers out of the target!

Comment: @DavidLeBauer No I didn't, I'll give it a shot!

Comment: @DavidLeBauer [Interesting!](http://i.stack.imgur.com/vs1ov.png)

Comment: :-) a dog! No, I suspect _Coprinus comatus_ or similar. Did you keep them around? Did they turn black and inky?

Comment: @DavidLeBauer I forget it in the fridge, a black juice came out of it and turned all of my roommates crazy. So yes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The shape, colour and scales on the hat suggest something in the genus [Coprinus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coprinus).

Some species are edible, but it is not recommended to have them with wine.
I would not advise you to eat them without further live identification by someone knowledgeable. Photo identification is not reliable.

Comment: Coprinus comatus gills will start to turn pink then to black liquid in a couple days . That would confirm identification so next time they come up in the same area you will know what they are . Certainly looks exactly like them ; I have eaten many pounds of them.